# Отправка кода на почту

Tags: java, android-studio

В Android Studio у меня есть фрагмент регистрации в приложении.

Хочется добавить функцию, чтобы когда все данные введены (включая почту), то на введенную почту отправляется код из 6 цифр. Новый пользователь должен ввести этот код, чтобы зарегистрироваться окончательно (чтобы его данные были введены в базу данных). Можно создать отдельную почту, с которой будет приходить этот код.

Comment: Надо сервак поднимать для этого и там весь код писать

Comment: А можете чуть-чуть по подробнее рассказать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб зачем поднимать сервак? Письмо из андроид приложения можно послать по SMTP без проблем.

Comment: @Roman Konoval можно, да. Правда надо будет пароль от почты в код зашивать. В итоге любой человек пароль получить сможет. И будет спам рассылать с почты или вообще пароль поменяет и приложение придется обновлять с новой почтой и так бесконечно. Небезопасно, в общем очень

Comment: Действительно, про пароль на клиенте не подумал. Если использовать гугл, то 
 проблему с уводом почты еще можно побороть используя application password (он не даст возможность логинится и что-то менять, только доступ к api конкретному приложению), а со спамом действительно никак. Пароль нужно хранить и использовать на сервере

Comment: Простите, господа. Так как я работаю с базой данных Firebase, то там уже есть встроенная функция по Email адресу. В любом случае, спасибо за информацию

Comment: Ответ на свой вопрос я уже нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Встроенная функция уже есть в Firebase, так что все хорошо.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]